# Exploring the Network and sharing files in XFCE/OpenBox/Thunar

Tags: linux, network-shares, xfce, openbox, thunar

As of recently I started using a debian-based distro called [crunchbang](http://crunchbanglinux.org/) which uses [OpenBox](http://openbox.org/) as a window manager and [thunar](http://thunar.xfce.org/) as file manager. I did setup Samba server correctly and can now share files back and forth on the network between my other machines (Windows7, Fedora) using [Gadmin-samba](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/12/25/configure-samba-with-gadmin-samba/) and manually accessing them through their network path (manually typing `smb://` URL in the address bar). However, what I'm looking for is:

1. An easy way to share files via right click -> share like in ubuntu & gnome/nautilus.
2. An easy way to browse through the network hosts and see the shared files also like in Ubuntu & gnome/nautilus.

I tried the following tips and hints but none of them helped much (or perhaps, there is something that I keep doing wrong):

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=304131
- http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/3735/samba-and-network-browsing/
- http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/samba_shares_with_thunar

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) An easy way to share files via right click -> share like in ubuntu & gnome/nautilus.

You can [create a custom action](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11636440&postcount=12) in Thunar via Edit->Configure custom actions.  Create an action to share a directory: `net usershare add %n %f "" Everyone:F guest_ok=y && chmod 777 %f`
And to stop sharing: `net usershare delete %n`.  Make sure the command will show up for Directories only on the Appearance Conditions tab.

> 2) An easy way to browse through the network hosts and see the shared files also like in Ubuntu & gnome/nautilus.

Try [pyNeighborhood](https://launchpad.net/pyneighborhood).

Answer (score 0):

Try sftp. Works in most networks. Type, for eg: `sftp://username@172.11.11.111` or `sftp://username@ftpserver.com` in the location bar of any file manager.